# How to save non-Ascii characters in redis HMSET?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, redis

I'd like to save Arabic characters like `سلام` in a redis hash, like this:

```
HMSET arabicHash "سلام" 5
OK
```

But the result is not as intended:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL arabicHash
1) "\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85"
2) "5"
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to save `سلام` directly inot redis set? And if not, how can I convert back `"\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85"` to human-readable charachters after being retrived?

Update: I've tested on my Ubuntu Bash terminal, but the result is not formatted correctly here. The screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to put quotes to enclose the key and value being stored in the hash.

[image]

Tested on try.redis.io ( it shows the redis output in utf-8 decode form )

2. The text may showup as utf-8 encoded in redis response, but on decoding, it would show correctly in arabic characters

Comment: Well, I'm tesing on Bash terminal. And I enclosed the arabic word in double quotes (like `"سلام"` . Please see the photo in my updated question.

Comment: Yes, your storage in redis is correct. See the decoded version : https://mothereff.in/utf-8#%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85